# populate dropdown list based on previous form inputs and data from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a form which asks customer for some details. I want the final dropdown list to be populated based on the inputs from the customer. The data for this dropdown list is taken from MySql database using PHP. here is the code i have prepared but it does not seem to work.

Form code:

```
               <tr>  
                <td><label>Trade:</label></td>
                <span class="text_11">
                <td><input type="radio" id="Buy" name="tradetype" class="listen" required value="Buy"/><radio style="font-size: 16px;"> Buy</radio>
                <input type="radio" id="Sell" name="tradetype" class="listen" value="Sell"/><radio style="font-size: 16px;"> Sell </radio></span></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>  
                <td><label>Item:</label></td>
                <span class="text_11">
                <td><input type="radio" id="Cloth" name="item" class="listen" required value="Cloth"/><radio style="font-size: 16px;"> Cloth</radio>
                <input type="radio" id="Fruit" name="item" class="listen" value="Fruit"/><radio style="font-size: 16px;"> Fruit</radio></span></td>
           </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td class="select"><label>Date:</label></td>
                    <td><select id="exdate" name="date1">
                <option value="2">Select</option>
                <?php include_once "selectdate.php"?></td>
                </select>
           </tr> 
           <tr>  
                <td class="select"><label>Amount:</label></td>
                <td><select id="noselect" name="noselect">
                <option value="1">Select</option>
                <option value="1">Choose Item</option>
                </select>
           </tr>
```

The Amount dropdownlist must be populated with data from MySQL based on the Trade, Item and the Date.

here is my jquery for this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#exdate').change(function () {

    var tradetype = $('[name="tradetype"]:checked').val();
    var date = $('select[name=date1]').val()
    var item = $('[name="item"]:checked').val();

    $('#confirm_tradetype').text(tradetype);
    $('#confirm_date1').text(date1);
    $('#confirm_item').text(item);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "selectamount.php",
        data: {
                "tradetype": tradetype,
                "item": item,
                "date1": date1,
        },
        success: function (data) { 
        var source = 
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: 
            { name: 'Amount'},
            url: 'selectamount.php'
        };
        var dataAdpater = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
        $("#noselect").jqxDropDownList(
        {
        source: dataAdapter,
        displayMember: 'Amount',
        valueMember: 'Amount',
        });
    }
    });
  });
  });
```

and here is the php query (selectamount.php)

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 

$form=$_POST;
$trade=$form['tradetype'];
$date1=$form['date1'];
$item=$form['item'];

$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT Amount FROM Contracts WHERE Trade='$trade' AND Item='$item' AND Date='$date1' ORDER BY Amount ASC"); 
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo json_encode($row);
}

$conn->db=null;
?>
```

Comment: check for errors and look at your (JS) console. *"does not seem to work"* - That doesn't say much really.

Comment: 'does not seem to work' doesn't help anyone in trying to find and solve the problem. Where does 'does not seem to work' occur?

Comment: the amount is not displayed in the dropdown list...

Comment: and what does this do/contain? `include_once "selectdate.php"` being for a `<select>`.

Comment: selectdate.php --> displays the dates from mysql database in the dropdown list

Comment: and I don't see a closing tag for your `<select id="noselect" name="noselect">` and if that also follows suit for your other select being what I wrote above about the include.

Comment: the select for date works perfectly. forgot to copy the closing tag here. have added it now.

Comment: we can change it to amount as well. it was just a name

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a bit with the code, this works for me:

form code change: add `onchange="getAmount(this.value);"` to the date select

```
           <tr>  
            <td><label>Trade:</label></td>
            <span class="text_11">
            <td><input type="radio" id="Buy" name="tradetype" class="listen" required value="Buy"/><radio style="font-size: 16px;"> Buy</radio>
            <input type="radio" id="Sell" name="tradetype" class="listen" value="Sell"/><radio style="font-size: 16px;"> Sell </radio></span></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>  
            <td><label>Item:</label></td>
            <span class="text_11">
            <td><input type="radio" id="Cloth" name="item" class="listen" required value="Cloth"/><radio style="font-size: 16px;"> Cloth</radio>
            <input type="radio" id="Fruit" name="item" class="listen" value="Fruit"/><radio style="font-size: 16px;"> Fruit</radio></span></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td class="select"><label>Date:</label></td>
                <td><select id="exdate" name="date1" onchange="getAmount(this.value);">
            <option value="2">Select</option>
            <?php include_once "selectdate.php"?></td>
            </select>
       </tr> 
       <tr>  
            <td class="select"><label>Amount:</label></td>
            <td><select id="amount" name="amount">
            <option value="1">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Choose Item</option>
            </select>
       </tr>
```

jquery code change: assign the data from the php to the amount select using its id.

```
function getAmount(val) {

var tradetype = $('[name="tradetype"]:checked').val();
var date = $('select[name=date1]').val()
var item = $('[name="item"]:checked').val();

$('#confirm_tradetype').text(tradetype);
$('#confirm_date1').text(date1);
$('#confirm_item').text(item);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "selectamount.php",
    data: {
            "tradetype": tradetype,
            "item": item,
            "date1": date1,
    },
    success: function (data) { 
        $("#amount").html(data);
    }
});
```

}

Php code change: echo the query result as option values.

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 

$form=$_POST;
$trade=$form['tradetype'];
$date1=$form['date1'];
$item=$form['item'];

$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT Amount FROM Contracts WHERE Trade='$trade' AND Item='$item' AND Date='$date1' ORDER BY Amount ASC"); 
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo "<option value='" .  $row['Amount'] . "'>" . $row['Amount'] . "</option>";
}
$conn->db=null;

?>
```